# NodeJS w/Express Error: Cannot GET /

Tags: node.js, get, express

This is what i have, the filename "default.htm" actually exists and loads when doing a readFile with NodeJS.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/default.htm'));

app.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

The Error (in browser):

```
Cannot GET /
```

Comment: Did any of the answers help you, or did you solve your issue another way? Please share..

Comment: Your question lacks details. Requests to which URL show you this error?

Answer (score 53):

You typically want to render templates like this:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('index.ejs');
});
```

However you can also deliver static content - to do so use:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Now everything in the `/public` directory of your project will be delivered as static content at the root of your site e.g. if you place `default.htm` in the public folder if will be available by visiting `/default.htm`

Take a look through the [express API](http://expressjs.com/api.html) and [Connect Static middleware](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/static.html) docs for more info.

Comment: How to do this for angular?

Comment: @SirBenBenji - this can't be done for Angular because it's a configuration in Express.

Answer (score 24):

I've noticed that I forgot the "slash" in the beginning of the Route as below 
and I was getting same error :

Wrong :

```
app.get('api/courses',  (req, res) => { ... }
)
```

Correct :

```
  app.get('/api/courses',  (req, res) => { ... }
    )
```

Answer (score 18):

You need to define a root route.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  // do something here.
});
```

Oh and you cannot specify a file within the `express.static`. It needs to be a directory. The `app.get('/'....` will be responsible to render that file accordingly. You can use express' render method, but your going to have to add some configuration options that will tell express where your views are, traditionally within the `app/views/` folder.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem, so here's what I came up with. This is what my folder structure looked like when I ran `node server.js`

```
app/
  index.html
  server.js
```

After printing out the `__dirname` path, I realized that the `__dirname` path was where my server was running (`app/`).

So, the answer to your question is this:

If your `server.js` file is in the same folder as the files you are trying to render, then

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/default.htm'));
```

should actually be

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
```

---

The only time you would want to use the original syntax that you had would be if you had a folder tree like so:

```
app/
  index.html
server.js
```

where `index.html` is in the `app/` directory, whereas `server.js` is in the root directory (i.e. the same level as the `app/` directory).

Overall, your code **could** look like:

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname));

app.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

Answer (score 6):

I found myself on this page as I was also receiving the `Cannot GET/` message. My circumstances differed as I was using `express.static()` to target a folder, as has been offered in previous answers, and not a file as the OP was.

What I discovered after some digging through [Express' docs](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html) is that `express.static()` defines its index file as `index.html`, whereas my file was named `index.htm`.

To tie this to the OP's question, there are two options:

1: Use the code suggested in other answers

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
```

and then rename `default.htm` file to `index.html`

or

2: Add the `index` property when calling `express.static()` to direct it to the desired index file:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname, { index: 'default.htm' }));
```

Comment: Thanks for this it fixed my problem. For some reason Index.html was fine in windows but I had to specify it in linux.

Answer (score 3):

Where is your get method for "/"?

Also you cant serve static html directly in Express.First you need to configure it.

```
app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);  
  app.set("view options", {layout: false});  //This one does the trick for rendering static html
  app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile); 
  app.use(app.router);

});
```

Now add your get method.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('default.htm');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a return to the index.html file.

`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));`

`app.get('*', function(req, res) {res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/build/index.html')); });`

Answer (score 3):

Provide full path for example I am running my app on https://ugoods.in/nodeapp

```
app.get('/nodeapp', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})
```

If you will run directly on http://ugoods.in or http://localhost

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})
```

Comment: thanks man. was tired from this. for future readers, I was hosting django as well as node app on the same server, so node was configured to run on different port and url, for example, my django project was running on "/" and node on "/node" so I had to add the full path in express post("/node/my-api")

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Solved it by small changes like below.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Got help from [here (ExpressJS Documentation - Serving static files).](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the static content was already being served:

```
app.use('/*', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../pub/index.html')));
```

...and everything in the app seemed to rely on that in some way. (`path` dep is `require('path')`)

So, a) yes, it can be a file; and b) you can [make a redirect](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.redirect)!

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) { res.redirect('/index.html') });
```

Now anyone hitting `/` gets `/index.html` which is served statically from `../pub/index.html`.

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem as mentioned in the question. The following steps solved my problem.

I upgraded the nodejs package link with following steps

1. Clear NPM's cache:

   ```
   npm cache clean -f
   ```
2. Install a little helper called 'n'

   ```
   npm install -g n
   ```

Then I went to node.js website, downloaded the latest node js package, installed it, and my problem was solved.

Comment: @knownasaliya this answer is for you

Answer (score 1):

```
var path = require('path');
```

Change  `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/default.htm'));` to
`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/default.htm')));`.

Also, make sure you point it to the right path of you default.html.

Answer (score 1):

You need to restart the process if `app.get` not working. Press `ctl+c` and then `restart` node app.

Answer (score 1):

"Cannot  " happens when a request is sent to non-defined target.
For example:

```
app.get('/',()=>{});
```

This would handle requests sent to `localhost/` but not `localhost/path`.

Please, make soure there is a routing defined for the URL you are trying to access.
Actual response you might get:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot GET /path</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was also getting the same error as "Cannot GET /" in my MERN application in the network tab. I added these lines of code in my index.js(in backend) file after referring to this article https://coursework.vschool.io/deploying-mern-app-to-heroku/ :

Right before my app.listen():

```
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
});
```

and also changed a line in

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production')
```

from this:

```
app.use(express.static('./client/build'));
```

to this:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build")))
```

So, check this too, if making these changes work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact issue, my error source might differ to what your source of error was though.

However, as for me, it was because I was running the app instance on CPanel inside subfolder as:

```js
app.get("/", (request, response) => {
       response.status(200).send("Hello there");
})
```

Results:

```
Can not GET /
```

So, I realized I was setting wrong parameter, and what I did was:

```
app.get("/foldername/", (request, response) => {
       response.status(200).send("Hello there, it works!");
 })
```

Results:

```
Hello there, it works!
```

Answer (score -1):

Another solution is to check whether your `.static()` parameter refers to the correct folder of your other website files (.html, .css, ..).
this folder should be in the same directory of the server.js file.
don't know why though, I tried to put it in a different directory and pass ./website for example but it didn't work. :/

Comment: is this answer or you're trying to comment your opinion about question? can you clarify?

Comment: It's an answer, I had a similar question and other answers here didn't solve my problem.
that's why I added this answer in case someone needed it in the future. :D
I edited my answer.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of using "app.use", try to use "app.get". It works on my machine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.