# Nginx w/ Express & Forever - Cannot GET /

Tags: node.js, nginx, express, digital-ocean

I looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13339695/nodejs-w-express-error-cannot-get), but nothing helped. I'm trying to configure `localhost:3000` to be proxied to port 80. Here's my nginx config (located in `sites-enabled` and `sites-available`):

```
server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    server_name fit-forms;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/fit-forms.log;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

I get `Cannot GET /` when I visit the IP (this is on DigitalOean). None of the static files show up. Here's my express code:

```
var express = require('express'),
  livereload = require('connect-livereload'),
  config = require('./config'),
  app = express(),
  env = app.get('env'),
  port = process.env.PORT || config.serverPort || 3000;

if (env === 'development') {
  app.use(livereload());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
}

app.use(express.compress());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.json());

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.listen(port);
console.log('Express server (' + env + ') running on port ' + port);
```

I'm assuming my nginx config is lacking..

Comment: You are not setting a value for root in your server block.  Do you have a default elsewhere?

Comment: Ah, that might be the issue. Although, why would it work on my local machine?

Comment: It may not be the issue, especially since you are using a proxy anyway, but it just was something I noticed comparing to my own files.

Comment: Did you try to curl localhost:3000 while ssh'ed into your server to see if it's nginx config or a problem with the node server?

Comment: I'll give these a try once I can. Thanks for the feedback! I'll let you know if any worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same situation.

The key is in this value:

```
__dirname + '/public'
```

Just try to output it e.g.

```
res.send(__dirname + '/public')
```

and you will probably will see the origin of the issue.

In my case the category of the nodejs app and the public_html directory were on the same level and the nodejs script was unable to find it.

So I changed it this way:

```
__dirname + '/../public'
```